Is Craft Commerce a feasible platform for an e-comm site with an inventory of 2000+ items?
I only develop websites on either Craft CMS / Commerce or Shopify. I much prefer to use Craft CMS when I can, however, I've only ever used Craft Commerce for sites where it's predominantly brochure, with some e-comm requirements.
My client runs a bulk grocery business with a big inventory 2000+ and, whilst we'll manage most of the inventory via Zoho Inventory, I'm concerned Craft Commerce might not do as a good a job of handling that number of products (vs Shopify).
Does anybody have some advice to push me in either direction here?
